# Which one of these two sample codes implement polymorphism?

Tags: java, methods, polymorphism

I am actually studying for a final examen of my first level of OOP (we use Java), and I need to be conceptually correct in terms of OOP.

So, I have this code:

```
Light.turnOn(pc);
Light.turnOn(car);
```

Etc...

And this other one:

```
pc.turnOn();
car.turnOn();
```

I have not yet implemented the first one. The second one, I did it like this...

```
class pc extends Light { ... }
class car extends Light { ... }
```

Where `Light` is an `abstract` class. Each different class, `pc` and `car` extends from `Light` and they implement their own version of the method `turnOn()`, in each of them.
In the first sample code (which I have not yet implemented), I would have different versions of the method `turnOn()` (in the same class), without "extending" anything.

So: which of the two codes implements/uses polymorphism? Why? How does the other example does not implement/uses it?

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Please follow java naming conventions.  Light.turnOn(...) implies a static method call, while pc.turnOn() implies an instance method call.  But the class name is pc.  This is confusing and misleading.

Comment: I think this question would be more useful if you put some complete code and respect coding conventions. Classes should have a name starting with an uppercase letter, you don't show the method that is overwritten and it is unclear what Light.turnOn(car) should be. If "Light" is a class, this looks like a call of a static method.

Comment: Good luck on your final.

Comment: Hello. I said in the post that Light was an an abstract class, and the two code samples are from two different packages; I am working on them separately to see how can I implement polymorphism.